# Can't Clone Git Repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone the repository at https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs/tree/master/TheActivityClass/Lab2_ActivityLab with the command

```
git clone https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs/tree/master/TheActivityClass/Lab2_ActivityLab
```

But it says it can't find the repository. This should be simple and I can clone other repositories. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you gave is not a repo, but a sub directory of that repo.

Try this instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs
```

Answer (score 1):

you can clone it with

```
 git clone https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android-labs/
```

Comment: Sorry. You both gave the same answer but Dan was first.